# NodeJS Joi Validation Error: item added into group created a dependencies error

Tags: node.js, serverless-framework, joi

So i have a two query string parameter and both of them are optional. I'm using nodejs serverless framework.

The two query parameters are pageNumber and pageSize. Basically, if none of these are supplied in query string parameters, it is fine, i will get all the values in database.

but, if one of them supplied, the other one should required. Example if the pageNumber was supplied, the pageSize should be required.

I can't achieve it, giving me an error:

```
× Unhandled exception in handler 'transactions'.
× item added into group pageSize created a dependencies error
```

Here is my code:

```
const Joi = require('joi');

const validateTransactionHistory = {
  queryStringParameters: Joi.object().keys({
    pageNumber: Joi.number().integer().min(1).when('pageSize', {
      is: Joi.exist(),
      then: Joi.required(),
      otherwise: Joi.optional(),
    }),
    pageSize: Joi.number().integer().min(1).when('pageNumber', {
      is: Joi.exist(),
      then: Joi.required(),
      otherwise: Joi.optional(),
    }),
  }),
};

module.exports = { validateTransactionHistory };
```

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways to achieve that.

#### 1. Use `Joi.alternatives()`

```js
const validateTransactionHistory = {
    queryStringParameters: Joi.alternatives(
        Joi.object({ // both required
            pageNumber: Joi.number().positive().required(),
            pageSize: Joi.number().positive().required(),
        }),
        Joi.object({}), // None of them
    ),
};
```

As you can see here, both fields should be provided or it must be an empty object, which means, none of them is accepted.

#### 2. Use `Joi.custom()`

```js
function pageRange(value, helpers) {
    if (!value) {
        return value;
    }

    const [{pageNumber, pageSize}] = helpers.state.ancestors;
    if (!pageNumber && pageSize) {
        return helpers.message('pageNumber field is required');
    }
    if (pageNumber && !pageSize) {
        return helpers.message('pageSize is required');
    }

    // extend your business as you wish
    return value;
}

const validateTransactionHistory = {
    queryStringParameters: Joi.object().keys({
        pageNumber: Joi.number().positive().custom(pageRange),
        pageSize: Joi.number().positive().custom(pageRange),
    }),
};
```

Here, we use a custom handler to get the full control in our hands. `helpers.state.ancestors` gives us the parent received object.

##### note 1:

I leveraged `Joi.number().positive()` to specify positive and greater than zero numbers.

##### note 2:

Please adjust the `pageRange` custom method as your business. I just tried my best to show the way. Maybe, it needs some improvements.

##### note 3:

The first solution does not provide a good error message. So, I courage using the second one and implement your custom function.

#### note 4:

You may not need to set the custom value for `pageSize`. Please test it, too.